# Html email align text and image

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm having trouble aligning an image with text. The problem only occurs in outlook 03,07 & 10. See this picture to get a better understanding of my problem: [image]

This is my code:

```
<td valign="middle" style="color:#fff;  font-size:18px; padding-left:3%;" width="600" height="34" bgcolor="#1a292f">
    <span class="nonmobile_content">
        Onsdag
    </span>                         
    <span style="font-weight: bold">
        21.03
    </span>                     
    <span style="color:#87bcd8;">
        2013
    </span>                     
    <span style="color:#87bcd8;">
        uke 11
    </span>
    <span>
        <img src="retriever-logo-top.png" align="right">
    </span>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#1a292f">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `align=right` at all. It s better to float img right. If you want it to be vertcially aligned just set the appropriate line-height to both - span and img.

Comment: @nd_macias actually, when authoring **html for emails** there is very little support for css (especially in outlook) so align="right" really is the way to go.

Comment: @xec True, I didn't notice that it is for an email template. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you're putting this all in one table cell rather than putting the image in a separate cell? You could simply:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        Retriever (1), Cision (2), ...
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ... >
        <span class="nonmobile_content">
            Onsdag
        </span>                         
        <span style="font-weight: bold">
            21.03
        </span>                     
        <span style="color:#87bcd8;">
            2013
        </span>                     
        <span style="color:#87bcd8;">
            uke 11
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="retriever-logo-top.png" align="right">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then rather adding `width` to each individual `td` simply add it to the table:

```
<table width="600">
```

Comment: This does indeed work! I just had to change my colspan="2" to colspan="3" and now it aligns nicely! Thank you =)